# Codeigniter: Auto logged in the newly registered user on the site and redirect to profile page

Tags: php, codeigniter, autologin

I am working in Codeigniter registration and login forms. I have created them all is working. now what i need to auto logged in user when it successful registered on the site.
**Add user code:**

```
 public function add_user() {
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('user_name'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email_address'),
        'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))
    );
    $this->db->insert('user', $data);
}
```

**Registration and validation:**

```
public function registration() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    // field name, error message, validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('con_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->index();
    } else {
        $this->user_model->add_user();
        $this->thank();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In else part,

```
else {
    $id = $this->user_model->add_user();
    // set session here like how you will set on login
    $data["user_id"] = $id; 
    ...// other required data for session
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    $this->thank();
}
```

In model return last insert id after inserting the data

```
$this->db->insert('user', $data);
return $this->db->insert_id();//   <--- this line
```

Comment: So in the session i have to get the USER email and password and then logged it in? can you please explain it little more for more understanding.

Comment: you mean you want to store email and password in session of logged in user??

Comment: yes. because i am logging the user in on the base of email address and password.

Comment: Show how ur setting session after login??

Comment: Here is first part:
 function login($email, $password) {
        $this->db->where("email", $email);
        $this->db->where("password", $password);

        $query = $this->db->get("user");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

Comment: foreach ($query->result() as $rows) {
                //add all data to session
                $newdata = array(
                    'user_id' => $rows->id,
                    'user_name' => $rows->username,
                    'user_email' => $rows->email,
                    'logged_in' => TRUE,
                );
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: in the same way, set session here also,

Comment: Same session for the registration function or add user?